# Items in shopping cart disappear

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

I am having a big problem on our websites. When I add something to the shopping cart it works good. But if I navigate to say the homepage the product disappears. But when I add another product everything reappears.

**UPDATE:** When I look at a computer of a collegeau I sometimes see the product I put in my shopping cart on the other computer.

Comment: can you please send you home page code or url?

Comment: You can check our webshop http://www.easytubs.nl

Comment: Check you session settings. And check cookie domain and cookie directory in settings. Did you switch to https?

Comment: After some digging I found the problem. Our hosting company has their own Full Page Caching plugin. Which was turned on instead of turned off at my request.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar behavior when someone hard codes a session key in a link somewhere (often it happens in an email newsletter, which is just a mess). Make sure your site's links do not have hard coded session keys in them.